# Why was I not awarded 'Lifeboat' when the conditions seem fulfilled

Tags: support, badges

I [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507225/can-an-activity-have-two-implements/17507258#17507258) a while back and thought I might get the [Lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat) badge for it once the answer reached a score of 20, but actually didn't.

To check that the score at the time of answer was below -3, I used [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1126248/1387904/test-query). It seems like the score was at -5 when I originally answered, so I am wondering why the badge was not awarded. Note that I got [Lifejacket](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8841/lifejacket) for this answer.

What am I missing?

Note that my answer had a score of 20 at the time this meta question was posted, although it is currently at 19.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the OP was at 1 point reputation when they posted I can’t make out for certain what the post score was at the time you posted. All that is certain is that it was at -4 **at most** when they marked your answer as accepted. All that that means is that it could easily have been at -2 when you submitted your answer which would disqualify the answer for a lifeboat badge.

I know it was not at -5 because they earned +2 reputation by marking the answer as accepted and the next downvote removed those two points again, leaving a time stamped entry in their reputation page. We know it was at -5 at midnight UTC so there was at least 1 downvote between accepting and the end of the UTC day. Had they had more reputation before asking the question the other 4 downvotes that were cast that day would have shown up there too, giving us a more detailed timeline. And we also know it was at at least -2 because you earned the silver lifejacket badge.

So yes, the question was at -5 by midnight, but that doesn’t mean that it was at -3 or worse when you answered. Even us moderators can’t know what the exact score was at that time, all other voting information (available in the SEDE or in the post timeline or other, moderator-only sources) is limited to per-day summaries.

Since you didn’t get the lifeboat badge we can only conclude that it wasn’t at -3 or lower when you answered, sorry.